# Customising a Custom Objects panel on an Account details page (Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I've created a custom object, I have it appearing automatically on the Account details page (think Quote example).

But the quote only has a name column, how do I get it to show other fields? much like the opportunities panel on the account panel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so simple really, here's how.

Goto --> Customise --> Accounts --> Page Layout

select a page layout.

Action "Edit"

This brings up a list of the panels on the page... scroll down...

You'll see one called "Related List Section"

these are the panels I was originally referring to.

Click on the "List?" you want to add fields to. (should be selected blue)

Click "Edit Properties"

wait for a dialog blog.. add the fields you want to be displayed to the right side.

Save... And SAVE the layout changed.

DONE...

hope one day this helps someone.